# How to hide a secret key on a user's machine(NOT your own server)?

Tags: python, security, api-key, secret-key, information-hiding

This question has been asked HUNDREDs of times, and there are HUNDREDs of articles on how to do this, but ***ALL*** of them only speak of environment variables, which won't work in my scenario, since the code will be run on the user's device and not my server. So the user can just open the `.env` file or check the environment variables I add to his system and get my secret key. I want my key to be fully hidden, even on the user's own device. HOW to do this? Please help me!
My code is something like this:

```
client = Client()
client.login('username', '<hidden password>')
```

How to hide the hidden password?

Comment: Everyone who knows how system debugging tools work will be able to trace any change your application makes to the machine and eventually find your secret. You should consider to give out secrets per device / user and adapt your architecture to this.

Comment: @KlausD. How would I implement that with python code? I don't fully understand what you're saying.

Comment: Don't permit that `'username'` account to do anything that you don't want the user to do, and then it's fine for the user to know the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's technically impossible to hide anything from a sufficiently educated user on their own computer (malware being one notable exception). This problem needs to be solved on the server side. The only reason why you may want to hide the password from a user is that you don't want to allow certain operations to be executed using the client or any other means. If instead the user account is only restricted to the safe set of operations, it can't hurt if the user knows the password.